# How do I transpose a dynamically sized and dynamic datatyping 2D ArrayLists in C#

Tags: c#, python-3.x, algorithm, arraylist, .net-6.0

I have this Python code that does it (I need a C#):

```
def transpose(self):
  return [[i[j] for i in grid_map] for j in range(min([len(i) for i in grid_map]))]
```

The dimensions can be any, including non-square, but x and y are bound by ulong's maximum value.

Lastly, I need to use ArrayList<ArrayList<dynamic, dynamic>> because I'll have different datatypes stored there.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the ArrayList class is a legacy collection type that has been replaced by the more modern and efficient List class in the .NET Framework. It is generally recommended to use the List class instead of ArrayList, unless you have a specific reason to use the older collection type.

Part of official Microsoft Doc to Array Lists:

> We don't recommend that you use the ArrayList class for new
> development. Instead, we recommend that you use the generic List
> class. The ArrayList class is designed to hold heterogeneous
> collections of objects. However, it does not always offer the best
> performance. Instead, we recommend the following: For a heterogeneous
> collection of objects, use the List (in C#) or List(Of Object)
> (in Visual Basic) type. For a homogeneous collection of objects, use
> the List class. See Performance Considerations in the List
> reference topic for a discussion of the relative performance of these
> classes. See Non-generic collections shouldn't be used on GitHub for
> general information on the use of generic instead of non-generic
> collection types.

[Link to Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-7.0)

1.You can use LINQ:

```
// Transpose the list
    dynamic[][] transposedList = list
        .OfType<ArrayList>()
        .Select(row => row.OfType<dynamic>().ToArray())
        .ToArray();
```

2.Or two nested for - Loops:

```
// Transpose the list
int rows = list.Count;
int cols = 0;

// Find the maximum number of columns
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    cols = Math.Max(cols, list[i].Count);
}

// Create a new 2D list with the same number of rows as the original 
// list's number of columns, and the same number of columns 
// as the original list's number of rows
List<List<dynamic>> transposedList = new List<List<dynamic>>();
for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
{
    transposedList.Add(new List<dynamic>());
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
    {
        transposedList[i].Add(null);
    }
}

// Copy the elements from the original list to the transposed list
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < list[i].Count; j++)
    {
        transposedList[j][i] = list[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Will the max size of ArrayList or List be up to ulong? I’m asking, because I potentially need up to that size.

Comment: No but max value of ulong is 10^19. If every object in your list needs 1 bit storage, you will need a ram with 1.25 exabytes...There will be no naive algorithm solution for that amount of data. you will need high parallel processing  (otherwise the transposing will take days/ months) and memory management to switch data blocks between ram and cloud/ disk etc.

Comment: ok, maybe not exabytes but petabytes quite possible.